# This code gets stuck and I don't know why

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_digit(int);

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter no. for which we want the sum of digits\n");
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    printf("Some of digit %d", sum_digit(a));
    return 0;
}

int sum_digit(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(num > 0);
    {
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
}
```

When I run this code it asks for value but as I hit enter it gets stuck. Not able to understand why it is not producing any results.

Is this the problem of whites spaces with scanf?

Comment: First of all indent your code properly.

Comment: `sum_digit` needs to return something.

Comment: `while(num>0);` <== infinite loop with empty body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. `while(num > 0);` - There is a semicolon `;` after the loop condition, which results in that the loop´s body won´t be treated as loop body - the `while` loop will just constantly proof the condition and as `num` does not change, the loop goes infinitely.
2. The function `sum_digit()` does not return anything.

   Thus, To use `printf("Some of digit %d", sum_digit(a));` invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

   `return sum;` at the end of `sum_digit()`.

   ---

Note: If you use GCC, the `-Wall` option had showed you warnings for both.

Answer (score 3):

`While` loops (as well as `for` loops and `if` statements), in the typical use cases, don't have a semicolon at the end. That being said, you have an extra semicolon at the end of the line: `while(num > 0);`. Remove the semicolon for the expected behavior.

As pointed out in comments, the function `int sum_digit(int)` will result in an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because it doesn't return anything. Add `return sum;` at the end of the function to fix that.

Here's the final code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_digit(int);

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter no. for which we want the sum of digits\n");
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    printf("Some of digit %d", sum_digit(a));
    return 0;
}

int sum_digit(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

Using a semicolon at the end can be [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155233/why-there-is-semicolon-after-loop-while) sometimes.

Comment: Sure, I can agree with that. I guess it depends on the compiler. I used the vs2017 c++ one.

Comment: Nice cat btw. I got 3.

Comment: Love that! :D I don't have any though, just found this somewhere online

Comment: And Visual Studio 2017 shows warnings and/or errors for no return value?

Comment: In vs2017 I get an error `error C4716: 'sum_digit': must return a value`

Comment: Update: Didn´t tried it with `-Wall` before. I was in a hurry. Me fool. - Then it actually shows warnings for both.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is infinite. You need to remove the semi-colon.
A while loop looks like this

```
while(condition) {
    statement(s);
}
```

Your while loop does nothing, but keeps running if `num>0`